# create RsaCryptoserviceProvider again

Tags: c#, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I'm working with `RSACryptoServiceProvider` and I looked at examples on some book and on the Internet. In all the examples, a new instance of the type is being created in every method it is being used.

Is it not recommended to create only one `RSACryptoServiceProvider` instance and reuse it in all methods?

Comment: Might be worth citing an example.

Answer (score 0):

No - create your own each time, otherwise, once you start using different keys everything is going to go horribly wrong, or if you try to iterate through and need to decrypt something else. Furthermore it has [thread safety problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/s575f7e2(v=vs.102)).

Comment: Explain more? Well, if you reused the crypto provider and it's accessed by two threads at once you're going to get incorrect results back. It's not as if it takes major time to initialise anyway, so why run the risk of premature optimisation like this.

Comment: That's the most obvious problem point - however you can't guarantee anything. Let's turn this around - why do you only want to create it once? It's a cheap object to create.

Comment: I was just wondering! Now I understood why it was not necessary to do it)